# How to take boolean field input from HTML into my Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have used Django forms for creating users and I extended the default User model by adding a boolean field, so I defined a new form for it. But I couldn't take input from HTML form to this boolean field. Shall I change my HTML form code?
Following are my code samples:

models.py

```
# accounts.models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SpecialUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flag = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxInput
from .models import SpecialUser

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]

class SuperUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SpecialUser
        fields = ['flag']
        widgets = {
            'flag': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'flag'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        sp_form = SuperUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and sp_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            sp_form = sp_form.save(commit=False)
            sp_form.user = user
            sp_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account created!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        sp_form = SuperUserForm()
        messages.warning(request, 'Your account cannot be created.')
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML form code:

```
<form method="post" class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <label for="flag">Special User: </label>
    <input id="flag" class="flag" type="checkbox" name="flag">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views.py you're creating a local variable for a `SpecialUser` form, `sp_form`, that is neither loaded into the context data nor templated in the HTML form code.

You can load `sp_form` into the context data by adding it to the context dict passed to `render()`. This will allow the template to see the variable. For example:

```
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form, 'sp_form': sp_form})
```

And then you can render it in the template. For example, underneath the main form:

```
{{ form|crispy }}
{{ sp_form|crispy }}
```

Comment: Thank you! Issue resolved. But how can I render SpecialUserForm attributes in an HTML file? Like I used ```{{user.username}}``` for getting username. But ```{{user.phonenumber}}``` is not working(which is attribute of 2nd form). Please help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

For starters this is generally not how you would want to extend the user model in a Django application. You would want to inherit from AbstractUser and add your fields to that model and run migrations. At least in this case, that would be ideal, then you could simply define the field on your RegisterForm.fields and let `{{ form|crispy }}` render the form for you. Naturally, you could call `form.save()` and move on with your life.

To clarify why this may not be working, it is generally not good practice to render your own fields for a form unless absolutely necessary. If you insist on doing it this way, note that Django prefixes the id with `id_` so in your case it would be `<label for="id_name">...</label>` and `<input id="id_flag" ...`

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge! I'm an absolute beginner. I was trying to do my intern tasks. Could you please suggest to me any books to go with Django?

Comment: Two scoops of Django is a great series. https://hackr.io/blog/django-books seems like a solid post from a solid source. Good luck in your adventure my friend. Keep breaking things and making them better and make sure you're having fun while you do it. Cheers